# How to set and get keys from scala TreeMap?

Tags: scala, treemap

Suppose I have

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

val tree = new TreeMap[String, List[String]]
```

Now after above declaration, I want to assign key "k1" to List("foo", "bar")
and then how do i get or read back the key "k1" and also read back non-existent key "k2"?

what happens if I try to read non-existent key "k2" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to "mutate" the **immutable** map is by referring to it in a variable (`var` as opposed to `val`):

```
var tree = TreeMap.empty[String, List[String]]
tree += ("k1" -> List("foo", "bar")) //a += b is sugar for "c = a + b; a = c"
```

It can be accessed directly using the `apply` method, where scala syntactic sugar kicks in so you can just access using parens:

```
val l = tree("k1") //equivalent to tree.apply("k1")
```

However, I rarely access maps like this because the method will throw a `MatchError` is the key is not present. Use `get` instead, which returns an `Option[V]` where `V` is the value-type:

```
val l = tree.get("k1") //returns Option[List[String]] = Some(List("foo", "bar"))
val m = tree.get("k2") //returns Option[List[String]] = None
```

In this case, the value returned for an absent key is `None`. What can I do with an *optional* result? Well, you can make use of methods `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `collect` and `getOrElse`. Try and avoid pattern-matching on it, or using the `Option.get` method directly!

For example:

```
val wordLen : List[Int] = tree.get("k1").map(l => l.map(_.length)) getOrElse Nil
```

---

**EDIT**: *one way of building a Map without declaring it as a `var`, and assuming you are doing this by transforming some separate collection, is to do it via a fold. For example:*

```
//coll is some collection class CC[A]
//f : A => (K, V)
val m = (TreeMap.empty[K, V] /: coll) { (tree, c) => tree + f(c) }
```

This may not be possible for your use case

Comment: AFAIK val in scala means we cannot change the reference to the object which val is pointing to but we can change the values in the object. So a higher performance solution is based on val and not var in above case.

Comment: @amc - only if a mutable structure offers higher performance, which (of course) it may not. Also, even if a single call is more performant, other requirements (e.g. safely passing the collection to another part of the program) may conflict with this - for example, you might have to frequently take a **copy** of a mutable structure. It's also worth pointing out that there is no mutable `TreeMap` in the scala standard library.

Comment: Thank you for your code but is there any way to do it while keeping tree as val and not as var?

Comment: @amc. No! You can hardly declare an immutable collection as an immutable `val` and then expect to mutate it. The only options available are to declare the `val` reference only after you have constructed the final version of the map, or to use scalaz's ST threads (not for the fainthearted).

Comment: @ziggystar - I hope you are ashamed of yourself

Comment: Good answer. Could you add the `updated` method as an alternative to `+=`, please?